# Can I create Workflows in Visual Studio 2008 for SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio

1. I have SharePoint 2010 and Visual Studio 2008. Is it possible to create workflow in Visual Studio 2008 for SharePoint 2010?
2. If yes on the previous question: What do I need to create workflow for SharePoint 2010 in Visual Studio 2008?

For example extra tools?, because right now I have installed SP2010 and VS2008 but I don’t know if this is enough.

## Edit

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (Professional Edition). When I generate a new project/Visual C#/Workflow/ I only see SharePoint 2007 State machine Workflow and SharePoint 2007 sequential machine Workflow. I can’t see SharePoint/2007 or SharePoint/2010 like your image what do you think? I don’t have the correct MVS version or I require to installed the templates.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visual Studio 2008 ships with templates for SharePoint 2010. There are templates for both "Sequential Workflow" and "State Machine Workflow".
2. Depeds on your need. For basic workflows perhaps SharePoint Designer 2010 (free) would cover the needs. But if you for some reason need more advanced workflows you could use the templates mentioned in answer 1.

Comment: Hello
First thanks for your time and answer

According with your answer I can create Workflow for SP 2010 in Visual Studio 2008

But for example right now I only see two options 
1-SharePoint 2007 Sequential Workflow 
2-SharePoint 2007 State Machine Workflow

Can I use these two options for SP 2010? Or I need to install something more.

Comment: Have a look at this page http://www.devproconnections.com/article/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-2010-developer-tools-in-visual-studio-2010
The first screenshot shows the layout of the templates in Visual Studio 2008, where SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010 are located at different sub-folders. What version of Visual Studio 2008 are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (Professional Edition) When I generate a new project/Visual C#/Workflow/ I only see SharePoint 2007 State machine Workflow and SharePoint 2007 sequential machine Workflow. I can’t see SharePoint/2007 or SharePoint/2010 like your image what do you think? I don’t have the correct MVS version or I require to installed the templates thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could try this? http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/